Cloudflare caching behavior regarding index.html file
My origin server is sending Cache-Control: no-store, max-age=0 with my index.html.
Cloudflare has all the defaults untouched(Edge Cache TTL & Browser Cache TTL). But I am getting some feedback from users that app is crashing due to old javascript bundle being requested after release (but not always and not all cleints), which can only happen when old index.html is served or retrieved from browser cache. I can not ask users for the headers they are getting with html.
But I always get the correct Cache-control header with html which tells not to cache the file (no-store)
The question: Is it possible that default cloudflare settings are overriding Cache-control for html ?
But if so I would be facing the same issue after every deploy.
